# iOS application - crash random for iOS 11.4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

We are having random app crash on button clicking.
here is the crash code - which crash only when the build is downloaded from the "testflight" where as while debugging it don't crash.

```
# Crashlytics - plaintext stacktrace downloaded by shanigee at Thu, 28 Jun 2018 14:13:01 GMT
# URL: 
# Organization: PopWOW
# Platform: ios
# Application: PW Gen
# Version: 0.2.1
# Bundle Identifier: com.Popwow.pwgen
# Issue #: 66
# Issue ID: 5b3155a86007d59fcdd32ee4
# Session ID: bdba8bbbd66e42919f5288faf8b79b48_DNE_0_v2
# Date: 2018-06-28T13:45:00Z
# OS Version: 11.4.0 (15F79)
# Device: iPhone 6s
# RAM Free: 1.5%
# Disk Free: 5.9%

#0. Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  PopWOW                   0x100aebc98 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads (CLSProcess.c:376)
1  PopWOW                   0x100aebc98 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads (CLSProcess.c:376)
2  PopWOW                   0x100aec10c CLSProcessRecordAllThreads (CLSProcess.c:407)
3  PopWOW                   0x100adb74c CLSHandler (CLSHandler.m:26)
4  PopWOW                   0x100aea204 __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke (CLSException.mm:199)
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x182e30a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x182e395bc _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
7  PopWOW                   0x100ae9c80 CLSExceptionRecord (CLSException.mm:206)
8  PopWOW                   0x100ae9ab0 CLSExceptionRecordNSException (CLSException.mm:102)
9  PopWOW                   0x100ae96b0 CLSTerminateHandler() (CLSException.mm:259)
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x1826e937c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
11 libc++abi.dylib                0x1826e8f78 __cxa_rethrow + 144
12 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1826f87ac objc_exception_rethrow + 44
13 CoreFoundation                 0x183404e18 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 664
14 GraphicsServices               0x1853e9020 GSEventRunModal + 100
15 UIKit                          0x18d421758 UIApplicationMain + 236
16 PopWOW                   0x100503a88 main (UICheckBox.swift:21)
17 libdyld.dylib                  0x182e95fc0 start + 4

--

Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x18353ed8c __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1826f85ec objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18354c098 __methodDescriptionForSelector
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1835445c8 ___forwarding___
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18342a41c _CF_forwarding_prep_0
5  UIKit                          0x18dc708a4 __109-[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout_EngineDelegate) _invalidateSystemLayoutSizeFittingSizeAtEngineDelegateLevel]_block_invoke
6  UIKit                          0x18d57457c _UIViewTopDownSubtreeTraversal
7  UIKit                          0x18d189668 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout_EngineDelegate) _invalidateSystemLayoutSizeFittingSizeAtEngineDelegateLevel]
8  Foundation                     0x183e8fb1c -[NSISEngine tryToAddConstraintWithMarker:expression:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
9  Foundation                     0x183e8f720 -[NSLayoutConstraint _addLoweredExpression:toEngine:integralizationAdjustment:lastLoweredConstantWasRounded:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
10 Foundation                     0x183e8b26c -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
11 UIKit                          0x18d448338 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2
12 Foundation                     0x183e8d500 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:]
13 UIKit                          0x18d448178 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke
14 UIKit                          0x18d123e58 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]
15 UIKit                          0x18d448274 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2
16 Foundation                     0x183e8d500 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:]
17 UIKit                          0x18d448178 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke
18 UIKit                          0x18d123e58 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]
19 UIKit                          0x18d448274 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2
20 Foundation                     0x183e8d500 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:]
21 UIKit                          0x18d448178 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke
22 UIKit                          0x18d123e58 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]
23 UIKit                          0x18d17526c -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _initializeHostedLayoutEngine]
24 UIKit                          0x18d1eb118 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_windowDidChange]
25 UIKit                          0x18d13c104 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:]
26 UIKit                          0x18d13c2f8 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:]
27 UIKit                          0x18d40e184 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke
28 Foundation                     0x183e8d500 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:]
29 UIKit                          0x18d123c40 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]
30 UIKit                          0x18d122b60 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]
31 UIKit                          0x18d1dffc0 -[UITableView _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]
32 UIKit                          0x18d21ee4c -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _addContentSubview:atBack:]
33 UIKit                          0x18d1a7464 -[UITableView _addContentSubview:atBack:]
34 UIKit                          0x18d459688 __53-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke
35 UIKit                          0x18d10f148 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:]
36 UIKit                          0x18d21b470 -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]
37 UIKit                          0x18d21816c -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:]
38 UIKit                          0x18d217d84 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:]
39 UIKit                          0x18d216aa0 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:]
40 UIKit                          0x18d2125ec -[UITableView layoutSubviews]
41 UIKit                          0x18d14f6f4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
42 QuartzCore                     0x1876c5fec -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
43 QuartzCore                     0x1876ca17c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
44 QuartzCore                     0x187636830 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
45 QuartzCore                     0x18765e364 CA::Transaction::commit()
46 QuartzCore                     0x18765f1e4 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
47 CoreFoundation                 0x1834e6910 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
48 CoreFoundation                 0x1834e4238 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
49 CoreFoundation                 0x1834e4884 __CFRunLoopRun
50 CoreFoundation                 0x183404da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
51 GraphicsServices               0x1853e9020 GSEventRunModal
52 UIKit                          0x18d421758 UIApplicationMain
53 PopWOW                   0x100503a88 main (UICheckBox.swift:21)
54 libdyld.dylib                  0x182e95fc0 start

#0. Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  PopWOW                   0x100aebc98 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads (CLSProcess.c:376)
1  PopWOW                   0x100aebc98 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads (CLSProcess.c:376)
2  PopWOW                   0x100aec10c CLSProcessRecordAllThreads (CLSProcess.c:407)
3  PopWOW                   0x100adb74c CLSHandler (CLSHandler.m:26)
4  PopWOW                   0x100aea204 __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke (CLSException.mm:199)
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x182e30a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x182e395bc _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
7  PopWOW                   0x100ae9c80 CLSExceptionRecord (CLSException.mm:206)
8  PopWOW                   0x100ae9ab0 CLSExceptionRecordNSException (CLSException.mm:102)
9  PopWOW                   0x100ae96b0 CLSTerminateHandler() (CLSException.mm:259)
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x1826e937c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
11 libc++abi.dylib                0x1826e8f78 __cxa_rethrow + 144
12 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1826f87ac objc_exception_rethrow + 44
13 CoreFoundation                 0x183404e18 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 664
14 GraphicsServices               0x1853e9020 GSEventRunModal + 100
15 UIKit                          0x18d421758 UIApplicationMain + 236
16 PopWOW                   0x100503a88 main (UICheckBox.swift:21)
17 libdyld.dylib                  0x182e95fc0 start + 4

#1. com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182fa3e08 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182fa3c80 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1834e6e40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1834e4908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4  CoreFoundation                 0x183404da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5  Foundation                     0x183e79674 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6  Foundation                     0x183e7951c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 148
7  UIKit                          0x18d106768 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8  Foundation                     0x183f89efc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183165220 _pthread_body + 272
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183165110 _pthread_body + 290
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183163b10 thread_start + 4

#2. com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182fa3e08 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182fa3c80 mach_msg + 72
2  PopWOW                   0x100ad665c CLSMachExceptionServer (CLSMachException.c:180)
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183165220 _pthread_body + 272
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183165110 _pthread_body + 290
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183163b10 thread_start + 4

#3. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182fc5d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183163eb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183163b08 start_wqthread + 4

#4. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182fc5d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1831640a0 _pthread_wqthread + 1420
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183163b08 start_wqthread + 4

#5. com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182fa3e08 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182fa3c80 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1834e6e40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1834e4908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4  CoreFoundation                 0x183404da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5  CFNetwork                      0x183d126e0 -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 220
6  Foundation                     0x183f89efc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183165220 _pthread_body + 272
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183165110 _pthread_body + 290
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183163b10 thread_start + 4

#6. com.squareup.SocketRocket.NetworkThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182fa3e08 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182fa3c80 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1834e6e40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1834e4908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4  CoreFoundation                 0x183404da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5  Foundation                     0x183e79674 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6  PopWOW                   0x100c2ac04 -[_FSRRunLoopThread main] + 4338772996
7  Foundation                     0x183f89efc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183165220 _pthread_body + 272
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183165110 _pthread_body + 290
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183163b10 thread_start + 4

#7. com.apple.CFSocket.private
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182fc5538 __select + 8
1  CoreFoundation                 0x1834ef378 __CFSocketManager + 644
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183165220 _pthread_body + 272
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183165110 _pthread_body + 290
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183163b10 thread_start + 4

#8. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182fc5d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183163eb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183163b08 start_wqthread + 4

#9. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182fc5d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183163eb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183163b08 start_wqthread + 4

#10. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x182fc5d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183163eb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183163b08 start_wqthread + 4
```

Anyone can suggest anything? - it does not crash while debugging ( we even enable NSZombie ) but when pushed to test flight it crash on the flow.

Any highlights or clue for identifying and solving this would be great help.

Comment: Try build application to simulator with release configuration instead of debug.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved it or this is the correct solution for your problem, but I faced the same issue, so edit my scheme to "release", then found this issue, "was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available". Then what I did was just changing the optimisation level from build settings to "no optimizaion".. every thing worked fine from then on..